# Booking via wotif.com using a US bank account permissibility

Tags: usa, bookings, money, exchange

Can I book a hotel in the USA using a bank in the USA via an Australian website, wotif.com? Does this exchange work?

Comment: Probably suboptimal as there’s a good chance you’ll be paying foreign exchange fees / spreads twice... beyond that, try, you’ll see...

Comment: Wotif is part of Expedia, so the transaction should go without hitch, and transaction fees may apply if the site _charges_ in AUD, although it wouldn't surprise me if it gives you the option of charging in USD

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but as mentioned in the comments it may cost you more if they charge in AUD as you will be paying for foreign transaction fees. It may be of more benefit to find that same hotel on a different website, that charges in USD.